# How can I create a property in C# for a nested private enum

Tags: c#, enums, properties

How can I create a public property in a class for a nested private enum?
I want to be able to use that enum also outside of this class but not in all places outside thats why I'm doing so.

I would also want to know if it is right to act like that or shall I use another convention, like writing the enum under the same namespace but than I will enable an global use of this enum by all the classes in the namespace which is not good.

Just to make it more clear: the enum holds different types of fuel
That's why I don't want electric car to know this enum and also other classes which can use it accidentally and are placed under the same namespace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do this. The compiler will complain about inconsistent accessibility. How can a method return something no one knows about? Make the `enum` `public` or `internal`, otherwise no one can use it.

Comment: Thanks but, in this case where should I place this enum should it be under the same namespace with public/internal or as a nested enum but with public internal access ? and what is the difference between the two conventions

Comment: @Mulder: How do you want this used? Can the `enum` ever be used outside of your assembly? Moreover, will your API be used by others? If so, it has to be `public`. If it's only used internally, then indeed, make it `internal`. As for the namespace, I like to put enums in the namespace where they are used, for organization.

Answer (score 0):

Specify the enum as [internal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7c5ka91b%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) so it will be visible to all classes within an assembly but not usable to objects in other assemblies. Like this:

```
internal enum MyVals
{
    val1,
    val2,
}
```

The obvious caveat is that you would have to make sure that you split your biz logic into separate assemblies, not just namespaces.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like your design is wrong.  I'm not sure of your classes, but maybe the design below may help you.  It's also easy to read and makes sense.

```
public class BaseCar
{
  //Basic functions for other cars to use
  void Drive();
  void Stop();
}

public class GasCar : BaseCar
{
  // Enum is specific to a car with gas
  public Enum FuelType ....
}

public class ElectricCar : BaseCar
{
  //No gas FueType Enum for electric car...
}
```